# Tasks in SQL Server and multiple worker role instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-worker-roles

Consider the following table in SQL Server: *Tasks (Payload nvarchar, DateToExecute datetime, DateExecuted datetime null)*.

Now we have two worker processes (2 Azure worker role instances in our case). Both of them periodically try to get records where *DateExecuted IS NULL AND DateToExecute <= GETDATE()*. Then they process that record and set (SQL update) *DateExecuted* to current date.

The problem is that a single task should be processed only once by a single worker instance.

What's the best way to provide **synchronization or locking** for implementing such scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Azure inter-role synchronization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258692/azure-inter-role-synchronization)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do locking over multiple roles/instances in Windows Azure is by using blob leases. Steve Marx created a great class for this called AutoRenewLease ([source](https://github.com/smarx/WazStorageExtensions/blob/master/AutoRenewLease.cs), [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/smarx.wazstorageextensions), [blog post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/managing-concurrency-in-windows-azure-with-leases)). If you already have a timer or while loop, you can write code like this:

```
using (var arl = new AutoRenewLease(leaseBlob))
{
    if (arl.HasLease)
    {
        // Query Tasks table and do work....
    }
    else 
    {
        // Other worker is busy....
    }
}
```

Or you could use the DoEvery method which allows you to schedule your code every X minutes:

```
AutoRenewLease.DoEvery(leaseBlob, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), () => {
    // Query Tasks table and do work....
});
```

Comment: The storage client library also deals with leases now, which it didn't at the time Steve created that library.